# How to insert an element in a vector of pair of set? vector<pair<int,set<string>>>

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std-pair

```
    vector<pair<int,set<string>>>m1;
```

I am trying to insert an element where each int will hold several strings using set. How to insert an element in this?

I tried like this.

```
    vector<pair<int,set<string>>>m1;
    int p,n,i;
    cin>>p>>n;
    string s[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>s[i];
    m1.push_back(make_pair(p,insert(s[i])));
    }
```

But it shows error.
Help much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Please post the error you get

Answer (score 0):

[`make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) needs to take a key/value pair, so the `set` should already exist.

```
set<string> s;

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    s.insert(str)
    }

m1.push_back(make_pair(p, s));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
m1.push_back(make_pair(p,insert(s[i])));
```

to

```
m1.push_back(make_pair(p, set<string>{s[i]}));
```

The `std::set` must exist before you `insert` any element into it.